# Get average via AVG MongoDB using Lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to obtain the average and sum of totals of a collection in MongoDB, for this I do a **$lookup** which returns the information correctly but when I want to group it and obtain the sum of totals as well as the average, those two properties always return them as null

This is my MongoDB Query:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            $lookup: { // DATA OK
                from: 'sales',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'clientId',
                as: 'ventaPorCliente'
            }
        },
        { 
            $group: { // total_average and sum null
                _id: "$idClient",
                username: { $first: "$name" },
                total_average: { $avg: 'ventaPorCliente.total'},
                sum: { $sum: 'ventaPorCliente.total'},
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "username": "Peishion",
    "total_average": null,
    "sum": 0,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "1010",
    "username": "BENJAMIN",
    "total_average": null,
    "sum": 0,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

How can i access to **ventaporCliente.total**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `$` sign, also unwind the `ventaPorCliente` array, as $lookup pushes the matching objects in an array. Try this:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            $lookup: { 
                from: 'sales',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'clientId',
                as: 'ventaPorCliente'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$ventaPorCliente"
        }
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: "$idClient",
                username: { $first: "$name" },
                total_average: { $avg: '$ventaPorCliente.total'},
                sum: { $sum: '$ventaPorCliente.total'},
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

Comment: I just tried but it still doesn't work :

             $group: { 
                _id: "$idClient",
                username: { $first: "$name" },
                total_average: { $avg: '$ventaPorCliente.total'},
                sum: { $sum: '$ventaPorCliente.total'},
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }

Comment: Thanks now it does work, I tried it a while ago with unwind but as you mentioned before, I forgot the $ sign anyway. Thank you!